# Magento 2 Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute with CategoryInterface after migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, eav-attributes

after 1.x to 2.3
I am getting error as following in my System.log file.

```
[2020-02-06 13:29:01] main.WARNING: Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute '903' 
                        for entity type 'Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'. [] []
```

I searched for the value 903 with queries:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_datetime WHERE attribute_id = 903;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_decimal WHERE attribute_id = 903;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 903;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_text WHERE attribute_id = 903;
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 903;
```

there are no 903 values ​​in the tables above

with the query below I get a result:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = 903 ORDER BY `attribute_id` ASC
```

you can help me?

[of the tables on the left in the images only those shown in the image have attribute_id with value 903[enter image description here][1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzksh.png)

[image: db]
[image: db2]

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether there is **attribute 903** in the table **eav_attribute**

Comment: attribute 903 in the table eav_attribute is not present

Comment: There are 2 options for you: 1- create a new attribute 903 in that table. 2- Delete the col which have attribute_id = 903 in the table "catalog_product_entity_int"